# Compact letter display from pairwise test

Tags: r, pairwise

I would like to create a compact letter display from a post-hoc test I did on a linear mixed effect model (lmer)

Here is an example of what I would like when I do a pairwise t.test

`df <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/Dzfh7b2f", header=T,sep="")`

```
library(rcompanion)
library(multcompView)
```

```
PT <- pairwise.t.test(df$fit,df$treatment, method=bonferroni)
PT = PT$p.value
PT1 = fullPTable(PT)
multcompLetters(PT1,
                compare="<",
                threshold=0.05,
                Letters=letters,
                reversed = FALSE)
```

**This works our great**, because from the pairwise.t.test, it is easy to simply extract the p values, and create the table I would like.

Now lets say I run a linear model, do a pairwise comparison, and would like to also create a table, as I did above, that creates a compact letter display for me from the extracted pvalues

```
library(multcomp)
mult<- summary(glht(model, linfct = mcp(treatment = "Tukey")), test = adjusted("holm"))
mult
```

I can see the p values, but have spent the last 2-3 hours trying to figure out how to just extract those values (as I did above with the pairwise.t.test), and subsequently, create a compact letter display table.

Any help is much appreciated. All the best

Comment: See `help("cld")`.

Comment: How would seeing ```help("cld")``` help me extract the information needed to create the table I would like to make? I feel like each pairwise test is very specific to extract the needed information, as is the case with this linear model question

Comment: Have you read it? You write that you would like to "subsequently, create a compact letter display table". That's what `cld` does.

Comment: Hello @Roland:  **I think I miss understood your comment** by reading over it too quickly. 

I followed your suggestion and got it to work nicely.

I appreciate your advice. I got the answer from it that I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Find more details [here](https://schmidtpaul.github.io/DSFAIR/compactletterdisplay.html).

```r
mod <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = iris)

mod_means_contr <- emmeans::emmeans(object = mod,
                                    pairwise ~ "Species",
                                    adjust = "tukey")

mod_means <- multcomp::cld(object = mod_means_contr$emmeans,
                           Letters = letters)

### Bonus plot
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mod_means,
       aes(x = Species, y = emmean)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower.CL, 
                    ymax = upper.CL), 
                width = 0.2) +
  geom_text(aes(label = gsub(" ", "", .group)),
            position = position_nudge(x = 0.2)) +
  labs(caption = "Means followed by a common letter are\nnot significantly different according to the Tukey-test")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion by @roland, the answer is simply:

```
mult<- summary(glht(model, linfct = mcp(treatment = "Tukey")), test = adjusted("holm"))

letter_display <- cld(mult)

letter_display
```